# Regarding useState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props, use-state, react-component

I'm trying to understand basic fundamentals of React like useState, props, lifting the state up etc. I have an input field and a button, I want to to type something into the input field, press the button, and have that text appear lower down in the component.  My component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './component2.css';


const Component2 = () => {
    const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState('');

    const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
    }

    const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
    }

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div>
                <label>Component 2</label>
                <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                    <label>type here:</label>
                 <input 
                        type="text"
                        onChange={valueChangeHandler}
                        
                    />
                 <button type="submit">add value</button>   
                </form>
                <div className="center">
                    {enteredValue}
                </div>
           </div>   
        </div>

    );
}

export default Component2;
```

Right now the text changes directly when I type and the button does nothing.
I tried all sorts of things but I'm missing some fundamental piece. In my app.js file, I have 3 of these components each with text inputs, my goal is to have buttons that paste the text from each component to the other components.

Comment: Your form submission function `submitHandler` does nothing, so your form submit button also does nothing.

Comment: I know, that was left over from stuff I tried

Answer (score 0):

The text changes when you type because

```
<input ... onChange={valueChangeHandler} />
```

So when you type into this input (onChange) `valueChangeHandler` is run and the state variable is updated. When you submit the form you do nothing.

If you want `enteredValue` to update when the form is submitted remove `onChange` from the input and only update `enteredValue` in you submit handler.

Comment: this actually doesn't work for me, the event.target.value that I get back from submitHandler is undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input to be displayed only when you press the button, you have to define another state below your current state, say:

```
const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false)
```

Then you may change the state from 'false' to 'true' on Submit.

```
const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setDisplay(true)
}
```

Then you can toggle the visibility of the value based on whether display is `true` or `false`.

So instead of `{enteredValue}`
You may write:

```
{display ? enteredValue : null}
```

Comment: I got it to work! not that way exactly, but i defined another State and got it work

Answer (score 0):

Your form submit handler does nothing.

```
      const submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
//do something
      };
```

You said:

> my goal is to have buttons that paste the text from each component to
> the other components.

So you need to send the text up to the parent component from each component via button click, then pass those down as props. You can do this by passing in the second array argument of the `useState` declaration down as a prop.

I'm happy to give you a demo but I need more info.

Does ComponentA's text need to go to ComponentB? What's the aim here?

Comment: I know about the form submit, that was leftover from other attempts

Comment: and yes, as an exercise I have 3 card components side by side. In each I have 3 buttons and an input field. One button adds the input to the component that it's in, the other 2 buttons add the input the other 2 components. Im going to keep building on this exercise as I learn more concepts.